# How to prevent update_attributes! shortcutting callbacks?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to check before saving event so I can throw an alert everytime a specific field gets updated. 
I tried to use "changed" to detect it but update_attributes shortcut the db validation so there is no way for me to use changed?

For example this notices the change:

```
m = Player.new
m.name = "Tom"
m.changed?  
=> true
```

But this does not:

```
m = Player.new
m.update_attributes!(name: "John")
m.changed?  
=> false
```

Any ideas how I can do this differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`changed?` returns `true` if there is non-persisted changes on your object. After your call, the object is up to date -- hence the `false` return. Check the `ActiveModel::Dirty` module, there is several utilities in it to deal with changes on object. `previous_changes` could do the trick, and maybe there is a more suited method to your use case.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to previous_changes and it worked. But I found a better option of Ruby metaprogramming, I ended up m.name_changed? m.name_was

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `changed?` refers to changes made since the last save point. Calling `update_attributes!` has the effect of saving it and applying your changes.

The `changed?` method and associated calls will only return things that have not been saved.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
m.attributes = {name: "John"}
```